# Show Social Sharing Buttons And Facebook Comments In Lightbox Modal Dialog (Image Overlay)?

Tags: comments, gallery, facebook

I would like to show Facebook comments and share buttons in the lightbox modal dialog (image overlay) that pops-up when I click on an image in gallery.

A lot like what they have done [on this website](http://www.premierlife.ca/gallery/cabin-fever-wednesdays-jbrs-11-02-11/) for instance (if you click on one of the thumbs nails you will see what i mean.)

How do I do it?

Comment: The picutres that they are commenting on are funn pictures that i have found and people have uploaded such as on funnyjunk where people leave comments and like the image it works very well and i have the same sort of thing on one of my other sites and it worked amazingly well in promoting the website and i got an insane amount of viewers because people shared and liked the content on my other site.

Comment: can anyone help at all?

Answer (score 2):

You can show Facebook and Pinterest sharing tools on the Nextgen lightbox with this tool:

http://sharemygallery.com

You want a facebook comment box. Unfortunately, this doesn't do that.  This plugin puts Facebook and Pinterest sharing buttons at the bottom of the image browser.

It may help you if you just want to get people stared sharing your NextGen gallery images...

Disclosure: This is my own plugin, my first one actually, and any feedback is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

THIS IS A MODIFICATION OF COLORBOX/LIGHTBOX PLUGIN .Colorbox/LIGHTBOX with facebook,twitter,google plus sharing and  facebook comments integration.

This also works with Nextgen or another gallery.
I just searched over internet for this but unfortunately I came with empty handed.

Here is my solution in a wordpress site

Here is the **demo**
http://maruf.sahajjo.com/wp_mr_workshop/photo-gallery/

If you think , this suits your need, then download the code.
https://www.dropbox.com/s/fietxxohy4lxgh4/lightboxsocialshare.zip

You may be have a look @ line 233 of shutterreloade.js This line simply tells you to load the socialsharingzone.php in the ifame  after the image.There I just send url of the image to share using FB api,twiiter api,gplus api.

```
var v = $("#lightbox-image")[0].src;
$('#shComments').attr('src', 'socialsharingzone.php?w='+(intWidth)+ "&url="+ v);
```

ALSO look at line 30-34 of **shuterreload.js**

```
imageLoading:'colorboxpluginimage/lightbox-ico-loading.gif',
imageBtnPrev:'colorboxpluginimage/lightbox-btn-prev.gif',
imageBtnNext:'colorboxpluginimage/lightbox-btn-next.gif'
imageBtnClose:'colorboxpluginimage/lightbox-btn-close.gif'
imageBlank:'colorboxpluginimage/lightbox-blank.gif',
```

I think rest things are pretty easy.
 
Try to use with a real{SERVER} url of the picture .Otherwise, Facebook like and comments will not work[SEE THE FACEBOOK RULES]
 If you find any difficulties, let me know. I am happy to answer you.

Comment: Please clean this answer up by removing UNNECESSARY CAPITALIZATION, (use editor tools to indicate _emphasis_, **strong**, `etc`.). Also please remove unnecessary information such as how much you enjoy the site, your life story, etc. This extra reading doesn't help users find information. Thanks.

Comment: I spent too much time on writing this code.I just share my opinion.I just share this plugin with everyone, so everyone can use it at free of cost.

Comment: I spent too much time reading this answer :/

Comment: @michal-mau, Can you please tell if this plugin meets your need?If not ,let me know.I am happy to answer  you.I am  new here at stackexchange

Comment: My comment was not pointed to the quality of your plugin! I was more concerned with the overall quality of your answer as mentioned by @GhostToast and with your reply to him. Please follow his advices on how to make your answer more readable, relevant and helpful.

Comment: This is looking much better. Thanks @RockerMaruf for your edits!

Comment: Thanks @GhostToast  for your suggestion.Hope I will keep doing better.

Comment: No worries .) Welcome to WPSE!!

Comment: Please msg me if you need hep to integrate this.I will be keep updating so this plugin can be used in the fly anywhere

Answer (score 0):

Is that what you're looking for ?

http://www.flexostudio.com/flexo-social-gallery.html

Flexo is a addon to the Nextgen gallery plugin, adding Facebook comments and likes to each photo.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use http://www.socialgalleryplugin.com - that adds social commenting (facebook and disqus) and sharing (twitter, facebook likes and pinterest)

...it also works with NextGen

Comment: You must disclose your affiliation.

Comment: Sorry...Creator..